# How to control the collapsing order of a WrapPanel in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

Is it possible, using only XAML and no custom controls, to visually control the order at which a WrapPanel collapses in WPF?

Here is my scenario:
[image: Scenario]

**Notes:**

- Items A, B, and C are all horizontal StackPanels with a fixed width.
- A and B must HorizontalAlign to the *Left*, and C must HorizontalAlign to the *Right*.
- The toolbar WrapPanel is in a column with a ColumnDefinition width of "*".

Comment: Is your WrapPanel at a fixed width or can it change?

Comment: xaml only / no custom controls, I'd say no. If someone comes up with a way, I'd really like to see it!

Comment: We had the same problem, in the end i wrote a complete new toolbar control, which works perfectly. The problem was, we needed the overflow on priority not on which the right most element was. But it is not to difficult to write a custom panel for that.